# How to align elements in different containers?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

How can I align my title with the left edge of my "Aligned right" container? Here is a sketch of what I am trying to achieve:

[image: mockup]

I  am using a `flexbox` and `flex: 1` to create a 50/50 layout. I am now trying to put a title in the right place. My first thought was to put it inside the `aligned-right` child container, however I don't want it to extend into the `aligned-left` area.

Is aligning the child containers to the center line with a flexbox the wrong way of going about this?

Here is a fiddle that lacks that title:
https://jsfiddle.net/cwasdbo4/17/

Comment: the *aligned right* has a variable width?

Comment: No, it is a fixed size. But the _aligned left_ is variable.

Comment: then you can add to the title `margin-left:calc(50%- w)` where `w` is the fixed size

Comment: Please post enough code to reproduce the problem in the question itself.

Comment: Temani Afif's suggestion is what I settled with.

Answer (score 0):

You may put .title container to .aligned-right container and add (according to your fiddle example):

```
    .title {
      margin-top:-20px;
      position:relative;
      width:200%; //or white-space:nowrap;
    }
    .parent-container {
      margin-top:40px;
    }
```

but it won't work for long titles with two and more lines (or if you add content dynamically) and absolutely helpless for relative layout.

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple example using  CSS flex

```js
var off=$('#box-left').position().left-9;

$('.header > span').css('left',off+'px');
```

```css
.main{
  width:100%;
  border:1px solid #000;     
}

.main .header{
   text-align:center;
}

.main .header span{
  display:flex;
  position: relative;
}

.main .container{
  width:100%;  
  display:flex;  
}

.main .container .box-section{
  width:50%; 
  height:130px;
   display:flex;
   background:#eff0f1;
  border:1px solid #000;
}

.main .container .box-section.box-right{ 
  justify-content:flex-end;
}

.main .container .box-section.box-left{ 
  justify-content:flex-start; 
}



.main .container .box-section.box-right .box{ 
  justify-content:flex-end;
  width:150px; 
  height:100%;  
  background:#0095ff;
}

.main .container .box-section.box-left .box{ 
  justify-content:flex-start; 
  width:120px; 
  height:100%;
  position:relative;
  background:#0095ff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <div class="header">
       <span> Main title here</span>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
      <div class="box-section box-right">
        <div class="box" id="box-left"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="box-section box-left">
        <div class="box"></div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This centers the title. I am looking to align the title with the left edge of the left box section.

Comment: what's your purpose for this type of layout?

Comment: This layout centers 2 contents to the middle of the page. The left content is fixed width, but the right content may expand. The content also has a left-aligned title. The purpose is to present details about an item to the user.

Comment: @user7733611it's not feasible with only CSS. you need to use jquery or javascript.
as per your design, I have updated my code above please check it again